# Find un-open workbook and print from specified sheet

Tags: excel, vba, printing, worksheet

I am creating a spreadsheet which links my customers to their regular orders. 
For example: John Smith has eight different orders. So I have one workbook for John Smith and eight sheets within the workbook (one for each order). It needs to be like this because the orders are lengthy and require simple editing.

The spreadsheet in construction has a drop down list for the customers (B3), a drop down list for orders (F3) and a print button (Button10). Therefore you select a customer, select an order and hit print. I want this to then go to the directory (C:\Users\Julian\Documents\Customers), find the correct workbook and sheet, then go to print preview mode of the correct order.

I have very average VBA knowledge (I know how to make a button print preview the current worksheet, but that’s about it). I already have a cell which automatically shows the workbook name (T6) in the right format and automatically shows the worksheet name (T7) in the right format based on drop down selections.

I was wondering if someone could help me with some code to print the correct sheet from the correct workbook based on the drop down selections. If it can’t find the workbook or sheet, I wanted a pop-up message that says “There is no workbook or sheet under this search criteria” or something along those lines instead of a generic coding error.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Julian.

Comment: Hi Julian. Your question doesn't show that you've made any attempt to solve the problem yourself and StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. You state that you have a basic knowledge of VBA so why don't you have a try at solving the problem yourself and then ask a question about any issues you encounter. See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on how to ask a good question here.

Comment: Hi @Aiken, the reason I have asked this question is because I tried reading other similar issues on this site but couldn't find anything that helped me enough. I obviously tried myself first but this level of VBA is way out of my capability and would love to learn and apply it. I tried lots and lots of other ways around it but nothing seems to be working, hence the post. It wasn't me being lazy or an attempt at someone else doing the work for me.

Comment: I understand that sometimes it's difficult to solve a problem you don't fully understand but by including your attempt answerers can help you understand why it didn't work as you hoped it would and then explain what **would** have worked instead. This way you learn something **and** get your answer. Understanding how Stack Overflow works helps us all participate in a meaningful and mutually profitable manner, if you ask good questions they get upvotes and answers, everyone gets rep, you get answers. Win-win :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer on Stack Overflow so please bear with me.

I work with databases for a living and I believe there is always a way to make things simpler, especially when you're using Excel, and even more so when you're open to using VBA. I suggest you upload  a sample John Smith file and I can show you how to set up a more efficient way for what you're trying to do.

If you just need a quick answer, try the following suggestions.

1. **Error Trapping When Workbook Does Not Exist**

   ```
   'Open the VBA Editor (Alt+F11) and create a new Module and paste the following code in: 

   Sub PrintOrder()  

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False  

       '-----------'
       ' VARIABLES '  
       '-----------'
       Dim wb As Workbook, _  
           ws As Worksheet, _  
           wb_Client As Workbook, _
           ws_Order As Worksheet, _  
           blOrder As Boolean, _  
           filDir As String, _  
           client As String, _  
           order As String, _ 
           sht As Worksheet, _ 
           xtsn As String

       Set wb = ThisWorkbook  
       Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")  
       'Insert your actual sheet name in place of "Sheet1" or use the worksheet number such as wb.Worksheets(1)  

       filDir = "C:\Users\Julian\Documents\Customers\"

       ChDrive "C"
       ChDir filDir

       client = Trim(LTrim(ws.Range("T6").Value))  
       order = Trim(LTrim(ws.Range("T7").Value))
       xtsn = ".xlsx" 'Replace the extension below with whatever format your file is in or simply use xtsn = "" if you've already included the file extension in the T6 cell  

       '---------------------------------'
       ' CHECK IF CLIENT WORKBOOK EXISTS '
       '---------------------------------'
       If Dir(client & xtsn) <> "" Then 'the workbook exists so open it 
           Workbooks.Open Filename:=filDir & client & xtsn 

           Set wb_Client = ActiveWorkbook  

           '---------------------------------'
           ' CHECK IS ORDER WORKSHEET EXISTS '
           '---------------------------------'
               blOrder = False
               For Each sht In Worksheets
                   If sht.Name = order Then
                       blOrder = True
                       Exit For
                   End If
               Next

               If blOrder Then 'worksheet exists so open its print preview window  
                   'EDIT// I originally set ws_Order to wb.Worksheets(order) but the proper workbook should be the customer workbook that just opened
                   Set ws_Order = wb_Client.Worksheets(order)  
                   ws_Order.PrintPreview
               Else 'worksheet does not exist so throw into error  
                   '//EDIT// I forgot the ampersand before the 'customer' string variable, which ruined the concatenation
                   Call MsgBox(prompt:="Order No. " & order & " has not been created for " & customer & "." & _  
                       Chr(13) & "Please create a new order worksheet before continuing." & _  
                       Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "     Error Code: A002", _  
                       Buttons:=vbOkOnly, Title:="ERROR: Missing Order Worksheet")
                   GoTo endProc
               End If   
       Else 'workbook does not exist so throw into error  
           Call MsgBox(prompt:="No client workbook was found for " & customer & "." & _  
               Chr(13) & "Please create a new client workbook before continuing." & _  
               Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "     Error Code: A001", _  
               Buttons:=vbOkOnly, Title:="ERROR: Missing Client Workbook")  
           GoTo endProc  
       End If  
   endProc:
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried applying that code and making the required changes however it was coming up with lots of errors. Definitely not saying it's wrong, but I'm more worried that the way I'm applying it is wrong!
How can I upload a sample file for you?

Just letting you know there are ~100 customers and each customer has ~5-6 orders each. So it will have to find the correct workbook, find the correct sheet and print preview it. I've worked on it for a while and believe this is the only effective way (allowing constant changes) with lots of unique images per order as well. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no problem. I spotted two major errors after running the code in Excel. I was missing an ampersand in one of the MsgBox calls so the error message I concatenated was all messed up. Common error and I should have spotted it if I had just pasted my code into a VBA editor; my mistake!

Comment: The other error was due to an incorrect workbook reference where I was basically linking the order worksheet to the original workbook (with the T6 and T7 cells) and obviously the order sheet did not exist in that file.

Anyway, I hope it works now. I'm assuming you read the commented out code where I put instructions on places you should put in your own information. Are you using an .xlsx file? If not make sure to change the xtsn variable.